# Should I always use the last version of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am updating an Android app which uses Google Play Services. Should I keep this library always up to date or should I always use the lowest version as possible?

Comment: What you add to your app is just the interface to Google Play Services. The services themselfs are an app on its own and will be updated independently from your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on what your app does and what functionality it needs that Google Play Services offers.

Straight from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview):

> If you want to access added features or products, you can upgrade to a new version of the client library as they are released. **However, upgrading is not necessary if you don't care about new features or bug fixes**. We anticipate more Google services to be continuously added, so be on the lookout for these updates.

Emphasis mine.

There is no general rule that says "always update it asap" or something, it is very situation specific.

Comment: How about the devices who do not have the version required by the app of Google Play Services ? Will I lose them ?

Comment: @poiuytrez as you can see in the image on that page, the play services app/apk is updated automatically without requiring user interaction.